# Which conformal maps UHP$\to$UHP extend continuously to the closure?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

> Does every conformal map of the upper half-plane $\{\text{Im }z >0\}$onto itself extend continuously to a map from its closure $\{\text{Im }z \geq 0\}$ to itself? If not, which ones do?

In [this](http://math.nyu.edu/student_resources/wwiki/index.php/Complex_Variables%3a_2010_September%3a_Problem_3) answer (written by a student, so there may be mistakes), some claims are made which I'm trying to prove.

First: *Any map $\varphi$ which has such an extension $\tilde{\varphi}$ is such that $\tilde{\varphi}(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$*. Why? Certainly I see that $\tilde{\varphi}(\mathbb{R}) \supseteq \mathbb{R}$, but I don't see why they must be equal.

Second: *In this case $\tilde{\varphi}(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R} \Longrightarrow \tilde{\varphi}$ is an FLT*. In trying to show this, I've considered pre- and post-composing $\tilde{\varphi}$ with a map taking the UHP to the disk. Then the composition is analytic, takes the disk to the disk and preserves $S^1$. If I knew it were bijective, I could show that it is of the form $$e^{i\theta}\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z},$$ but not knowing that it is bijective, I'm unsure of what to do.

Comment: I'm not sure that reading such sketchy materials is useful. The article looks like something a student would scribble on an exam without knowing how to prove the claims.

Comment: @PostNoBills Right, it's a particularly poor answer. Sometimes it the least bad option, if only to see why certain answers are not right.

Answer (score 4):

Boundary correspondence is tricky. I think it's better to show that the map is a  FLT, and only then  deal with the boundary.

Let's begin with the unit disk $\mathbb D$.

**Claim 1**. Every conformal map $f$ of $\mathbb D$ onto itself such that $f(0)=0$ is the rotation, $f(z)=e^{i\theta} z$.

*Proof*: Apply the Schwarz lemma to $f$ and to $f^{-1}$; conclude that equality holds, use the equality statement in the lemma.

**Claim 2**. Every conformal map $f$ of $\mathbb D$ onto itself is a  FLT.

*Proof*: Apply Claim 1 to $g(z) = \dfrac{f(z)-f(0)}{1-\overline{f(0)}f(z)}$.

**Claim 3**. Every conformal map $f$ of UHP onto itself is a  FLT.

*Proof*: Apply Claim 2 to $g  = \varphi\circ f\circ \varphi^{-1}$ where $\varphi(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ maps the UHP onto $\mathbb D$. Use the fact that FLT form a group.

**Claim 3**. Every conformal map $f$ of UHP onto itself is of the form $z\mapsto \dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with real $a,b,c,d$.

*Proof*. We already know that $f$ is a  FLT. Thus, it's continuous everywhere in $\mathbb C$ (except maybe one point), and the image of $\mathbb R$ is a circle or a line. As you know, it contains $\mathbb R$. Hence it is equal to $\mathbb R$. By the reflection principle, $\overline{f(\bar z)}= f(z)$, from where the conclusion about $a,b,c,d$ follows.

But actually there is no need to mess with coefficients at this point. Just note that the symmetry $\overline{f(\bar z)}= f(z)$ implies that if $z_0$ is a pole of $f$, so is $\bar z_0$. But a FLT has at most one pole. So, either there is a pole on $\mathbb R$, or $f$ is  linear.

Comment: Very nice. I have one question about your answer: suppose $f$ is a conformal map from $\mathbb{D}$ to itself. How do we know $f$ is injective?

Comment: I also posted this question here (sorry for getting impatient): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594688/conformal-mapping-of-disk-surjective-not-injective

Comment: (in the first comment, I should have said "from $\mathbb{D}\,$ *onto* itself")

Comment: @EricAuld People use the term *conformal* to mean various things. For me, in the context of  two domains in a complex plane,  "conformal map" means "holomorphic bijection".

Comment: The question may have meant it in your sense, in fact.