# Conformal mapping of disk, surjective, not injective

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Is there an example of a conformal mapping of the disk onto itself which is not injective? If not, how may we prove there does not exist such a map?

This came up in the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593616/which-conformal-maps-uhp-touhp-extend-continuously-to-the-closure) question.

Comment: By conformal, I assume you mean locally conformal, i.e. $f'(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$?

Comment: See [this question][1], and the answer to it.


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553299/surjective-immersion-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr2-which-is-not-a-diffeomorphi

Comment: @IgorRivin We're dealing with holomorphic maps here, they are much more rigid, that construction cannot be made holomorphic, I think.

Comment: @DanielFischer see the "personal remark" in the answer.

Comment: @Eric Auld:Do you mean the open disk, or the closed disk?

Comment: @user99680 Open disk.

Comment: @IgorRivin Ah, I thought of a different question, didn't look. I'm not yet convinced the answer is correct, though, must read it carefully.

Comment: @DanielFischer as penance, here is another link, which might convince you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185647/conformal-map-from-punctured-disc-to-disc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know a simple example, but here is a construction that works.

Let $D^2$ be the open unit disk, and let $U$ be a $C^\infty$ manifold diffeomorphic to the open unit disk. Let $f\colon U \to D^2$ be a $C^\infty$ map with the following properties:

1. $f$ is surjective but not injective.
2. $f$ is a local diffeomorphism.

It should be clear geometrically that such a map exists.  (See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553299/surjective-immersion-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr2-which-is-not-a-diffeomorphi).)  Then the complex structure on $D^2$ lifts via $f$ to a complex structure on $U$, under which $f$ becomes a holomorphic map.

Since $U$ is simply connected, the [uniformization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem) states that $U$ must be conformally equivalent to either the Riemann sphere, the complex plane, or the open unit disk.  Since $f$ is a bounded, non-constant holomorphic function on $U$, it follows from [Liouville's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29) that $U$ must be conformally equivalent to the open unit disk, so there exists a [biholomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biholomorphism) $g\colon D^2 \to U$.  Then the composition $f\circ g$ is the desired map.

Of course, the uniformization theorem is only an existence statement, so this proof isn't constructive.  In practice, though, many of the usual techniques for approximating [Riemann maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem) should work fairly well for approximating $g$.